# High Quality Round Corner Image in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

In my app, I want to high quality Image. Image is loaded from Facebook friend list. When that image is loaded in smaller size (50 * 50), its quality is fine. But when I try to get that image in bigger size(280 *280) quality of image diminished.

[image]

For round corner m doing like :

```
self.mImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
self.mImageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.mImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
self.mImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

For getting image m using following code :

```
self.mImageView.image = [self  imageWithImage:profileImage scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(280, 280)];

- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, YES,0.0);
CGContextRef context = CGContextRetain(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, newSize.height);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationLow);
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing (context, TRUE);   
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, TRUE);
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, newSize.width, newSize.height),image.CGImage);
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
```

}

I have checked my code several times, but could not figure out how to make image perfect. So, guys how this quality of image will be improved?
Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1):

> …quality of image diminished.

The 'quality' of the image is still present. *(Technically, you are introducing a small amount of error by resizing it, but that's not the real problem…)*

So, you want to scale a 50x50px image to 280x280px? The information/detail does not exist in the source signal. Ideally, you would download a more appropriately sized image, for the size you want to display at.

If that's not an option, you could reduce pixelation by means of proper resampling and/or interpolation. This would simply smooth out the pixels your program magnifies by 5.6 -- the image would then look like a cross between pixelated and blurred (see `CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing`, `CGContextSetShouldAntialias`, `CGContextSetInterpolationQuality` and related APIs to accomplish this using quartz).

Comment: @justin, I have changed my code according to ur suggestion, even now image is coming blur..Any idea,if I missed something?

Comment: @SuryaKant you can try a higher interpolation quality (`kCGInterpolationHigh`). again, i recommend downloading a larger image over processing in this scenario. it will still be clearly blurred with better interpolation, considering you are expanding it 5.6x in this case.

Comment: But I need same image from facebook friends profile Image and these images are 50*50 only. Also, I have checked with higher interpolation quality.But could not figure out something.

Comment: @SuryaKant if 50x50 is the largest image you can get, then you would have not much choice -- either reduce the displayed image size (e.g. to 100x100 with high interpolation) *or* expect poor image quality if you expand 5.6x.

Comment: @justin http://www.moronail.net/img/2010_see_if_you_can_enhance_that_license_plate

Comment: @jrturton hahaha :) i don't watch tv - never would have got the reference. reminds me of a joke i make with my friend about lossless encoding of additional video dimensions and additional audio channels.